# problem in understanding kibana graph setting ( significant links, certainty)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to use kibana to visualize some data using graph and I have problems understanding some of kibana's setting for graph visualization. in picture below you can see what settings I mean.

[image]

in particular I have problem understanding Certainty and Significant Links but other options being explained are appreciated too.

ty